# What is the default width of the cell border in tabular?

Tags: tables

I found that the width of the cell does not including the cell border. How to retrieve the width of the default cell border in tabular? Is it a constant or defined as a variable? I got 0.025cm (~0.7 pt) from my experiment with naked eyes.

Comment: `tabularx` does not change this so it is whatever you have set for `tabular`

Comment: your question is rather strange (questions are always clearer if you supply a small example document) because in tabularx you do not normally specify cell widths at all, that is the only point of using the package, it calculates column widths automatically.

Comment: @David I use m{xx pt} to specify the width in tabular package. Sorry for the misleading.

Comment: Your edit seems to be asking a second question, different from the original question, if I’m understanding it right.  If so, please ask it as a new question, instead of including it here.

Comment: @Peter Okay, I will ask in a new post.

Comment: I do not know of a package called `tabular`. Please edit your question so that it has a complete example document that shows the problem that you are having. I can not even guess what the question is currently.

Comment: @David Tabular is not in a special package. It is the default way to draw tables in LaTeX.

Comment: @KevinDong yes I know (I maintain that code) but why in that case did you say ..." in tabular package"

Comment: @David I am writing a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\the\arrayrulewidth 

\the\tabcolsep
\end{document}
```

Output: 0.4pt and 6pt

Comment: You may want to add a note to mention that the values of `0.4pt` and `6pt` are specific to the document class that's in use (here: `article`). Many (most?!) LaTeX document classes indeed use `0.4pt` and `6pt`. However, some document classes do not.